# how to assign values to multidimensional arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to do this with:

`arr[i][j] = 'whatever';`

but I get some kind of error "cannot convert to object..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you haven't initialized `a[i]` when you try to treat it like an array. If you haven't initialized `a[i]` to be an array when you say `a[i][j]`, then it will be undefined (or something else that isn't an array or object) and that doesn't know what `[j]` means, hence your "cannot convert to an object" error. You need something more like this:

```
var a = [ ];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    a[i] = [ ];
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        a[i][j] = 42; // a[i] is now an array so this works.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Like

```
a[3]["fieldName"]="xxxx";
```

Comment: That is wrong. Accessing arrays is done by index position. Same applies to multi dimension arrays. a[indexNumber][indexNumber].

Comment: you could explain the answer.That will help others if the answer is correct

Comment: you pushes the array as  Arr.push({
            TimeSheetID: 0,
            ProjectID: 1,
            ProjectName: "Test",
            TaskName: "My Task",
            TaskType: TaskType,
            Status: 0,
            IsNew: true
        });  and hence your array object contains 10 records,  If you want to change value of ProjectName property at 3rd index then you should write as  :    Arr[3]["ProjectName"]="xxxxxxx";