# Returning multiple values in an array

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have a nested array and I want to update that array with values in my database. It is based on a timetable: a 5 day week with 6 periods in each day. Monday is 0 and Friday is 4 in the array. There is period 0 up until period 5. When I execute this function it says:
Cannot Set property '6' is undefined
And my array is not updated
When I remove the "return" line, the error does not occur but obviously my array is still not updated.
Is this due to having multiple returns due to the loop. And if so how do i fix this? If it's another error please show me! If there is anymore information need please ask!

```
dayCountTest = 0;
    while (dayCountTest<5){
        console.log("2");
        if (dayCountTest == "0") {
            tempDay = "Monday";
        } else if (dayCountTest ===  "1") {
            tempDay = "Tuesday";
        } else if (dayCountTest == "2") {
            tempDay = "Wednesday";
        } else if (dayCountTest == "3") {
            tempDay = "Thursday";
        } else if (dayCountTest == "4") {
            tempDay = "Friday";
        }   

        periodCount = 0;
        while (periodCount < 6) {
            console.log("3");
            let db = new sqlite.Database('./linksdb.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite.OPEN_CREATE);
            let sql = `SELECT Link FROM `+ tempDay+`
                        WHERE Period = `+ periodCount + ``;

            db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                
                rows.forEach((row) => {
                    return links[dayCountTest][periodCount] = row.Link;
                    
                });
            });
            db.close();
            periodCount++;
        }
        dayCountTest++;
    }
```

Comment: maybe you have a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness, first

Comment: sorry for being stupid, but what exactly are you trying to tell me. ik im a noob lol

Comment: you take strict comparison `===` (same type, same value, ergo no type coercion) and check a number type with a string type. this is always `false`. please have a look to the various possibilities of checking a value in javascript.

Comment: still have no success with either === or ==

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have initialized the array links someplace else, because I don't see it here. The way in which you are trying to assign values (for the first time) for the multidimensional array is incorrect. Each element inside the array isn't defined as a sub-array at first. Solved this problem using a simple for loop that iterates over the first 5 variables (in this case) and assigns them as empty variables. This can also be made dynamic depending on the nature of the problem.

Oh and lastly, you combined a return statement with an assignment statement. That's incorrect.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845190/how-to-assign-values-to-multidimensional-arrays-in-javascript) link for more information.

```
    dayCountTest = 0;

    links = []; // declaring the array
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        links[i] = [,,,,,]; // making the first 5 elements of the link array as empty arrays of 6 length as there are six periods in this case
    }

    while (dayCountTest<5){
        console.log("2");
        if (dayCountTest == "0") {
            tempDay = "Monday";
        } else if (dayCountTest ===  "1") {
            tempDay = "Tuesday";
        } else if (dayCountTest == "2") {
            tempDay = "Wednesday";
        } else if (dayCountTest == "3") {
            tempDay = "Thursday";
        } else if (dayCountTest == "4") {
            tempDay = "Friday";
        }   

        periodCount = 0;
        while (periodCount < 6) {
            console.log("3");
            let db = new sqlite.Database('./linksdb.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite.OPEN_CREATE);
            let sql = `SELECT Link FROM `+ tempDay+`
                        WHERE Period = `+ periodCount + ``;

            db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                
                rows.forEach((row) => {
                    links[dayCountTest][periodCount] = row.Link;
                    
                });
            });
            db.close();
            periodCount++;
        }
        dayCountTest++;
```

This fix should get this code working right. Do let me know the outcome of this.

Comment: got that bit working, now the problem is that it says it is undefined, even though the value is something else

Comment: Ok then. If you could just give this answer an upvote and accept it so it gets known, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: logging the row.Link to the console after the line below, but nothing comes up, does this mean ive done somehting wrong with my database
links[dayCountTest][periodCount] = row.Link;

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I suspected.

Comment: A suggestion. Use the sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY opening mode for applications that don't require access to write to the database. This is safer and keeps data protected. Also, doesn't give the application the right to create an entire database if there isn't one under the specified name.

Comment: after fixing some more variable names, the original issue has come to problem:
links[dayCountTest][periodCount] = row.Link;
                                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot set property '6' of undefined
When i replace dayCountTest with an actual number, it works

Comment: When I checked for sqlite plugins for NodeJS, it showed me the function for opening the database is sqlite3.Database and not sqlite.Database which you have written. Is that a problem or is it a different version of the plugin?

Comment: nope dont think that is the problem, it works if i do it outside of a loop but only doesn't work when its inside a loop

Comment: i put a console.log inside the rows.forEach, logging the period count. It does not say 0,1,2,3,4,5 but only has 5,5,5,5,5,5. Does this mean there is something wrong with the loop?

Comment: The program would be quite slow as it has to keep opening and closing the database for every iteration in the while loop. Placing those commands outside is always better. As the periodCount doesn't change for each iteration of the rows array, the same number would be displayed. And I notice, you still haven't marked my answer as the correct one nor an upvote. We are dealing with a different bug right now and accepting and upvoting my answer is the right thing to do, so other people can know.